# Views custom sorting

Tags: 7, views

How can I create a custom sort of items in a view? For example, I want to order content by: **`(rating * 10) - age in hours`**. (Rating is 5 star module percentage.)

I've been looking at the [Computed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) module and the Views API but I'm not finding what I need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the end I created a custom module with a Views Sort handler to write the custom ORDER sql.

```
function custom_module_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if($view->name === 'viewname') {
    /**
     * Order = (rating * 10) – (hours old / 2)
     * Note: the rating field is divided by 2 because in the DB the rating is out of 100
     */
    $view->query->orderby[0]['field'] = "(if(field_data_field_rating.field_rating_rating, field_data_field_rating.field_rating_rating,0) / 2) - ROUND((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())-created)/60/60/2)";
    $view->query->orderby[0]['direction'] = "DESC";

    $view->query->orderby[1]['field'] = "created";
    $view->query->orderby[1]['direction'] = "DESC";
  }
}
```

For this to work you either have to add the SQL JOINS in this module or add the rating and posted date fields as a 'sort' in your view.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the [Views PHP](https://drupal.org/project/views_php) module for this matter.

> This module allows the admin account (user 1) to add fields, filters and sorts to views which use PHP code.

- Install and enable the module (along with Views)
- Add all necessary fields in your view and exclude from display
- Add a new *Global: PHP* field where you specify the code you need in order to calculate the desired result.
- In the value code add: `return (($rating * 10) - $age);` (also consult the collapsed *available variables* section).
- In the output code add: `<?php print $value; ?>`
- Add a new *Global: PHP* sorting field with: `if ($row1->php < $row2->php) return -1; else return 1;`

Comment: The rating is being provided by the fivestar module, how can I access the rating using $row->rating only returns the node ID not the nodes rating?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the fivestar module. If rating is a proper field that is attached on your entity (eg node), then you can simply add rating to your view.

Comment: Don't use Views PHP! Use real custom views code for maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

Using a field with the sort value ((rating * 10) - age in hours) will no work unless you update that field value continuosly (because it should change while time pass).

Probably you should write your own Views Sort handler. A Views sort handler allows you to set the sort order in the SQL.

In your SQL you will need:

- A computed column with your sort value: (rating * 10) - age in hours
- ORDER BY sentence using that column.

I've never written a sort handler but I think it could resolve your issue.

Check contrib modules that use their own sort handlers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I think I'll look into the Views Sort Handler as the computed_field doesn't appear to update in real time for each query and could be a little heavy on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can only sort the CURRENT PAGE if you use the `Global:PHP` field. However, if you have a pager and need the select query to order by that expression, you need to implement `hook_views_query_alter` and add the custom field.

First you need to add these fields in your expression at the view's *FIELDS* section, and then add the hook like this:

```
function MODULE_NAME_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query){

    if($view->name == 'name' && $view->current_display == 'page'){
        $query->add_field(NULL, 'TABLENAME.rating * 10 - TABLENAME.age', 'sort_field');
        $query->orderby = array(
            array(
                'field' => 'sort_field',
                'direction' => 'DESC',
            ),
        );

    }
}
```

Look for details in the document [add_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/plugins%21views_plugin_query_default.inc/function/views_plugin_query_default%3A%3Aadd_field/7)  of `views_plugin_query_default`